# inserting Cached .mxds into Flex viewer 2.5

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

I am trying to cache a number of operational layers in my flex viewer 2.5 application but after the layer type is changed from dynamic to tiled they are not visible in my viewer they are still visible in the Table of Contents widget. When I change them back to dynamic and reset they are still invisible. Is anyone familiar with this issue and have a solution?
Thanks,
jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the reference in the layer from being a dynamic to tiled? And have you actually built some tiles yet for the service that covers a extent you can see?
For test purposes I would enable dynamic-caching so it will create tiles as needed.